# How do output shape in cntk?

Tags: cntk

I write this code:

```
matrix = C.softmax(model).eval(data).
```

But `matrix.shape`, `matrix.size` give me errors. So I'm wondering, how can I output the shape of CNTK variable?

Answer (score 2):

First note that `eval()` will not give you a CNTK variable, it will give you a numpy array (or a list of numpy arrays, see the next point).

Second, depending on the nature of the model it is possible that what comes out of `eval()` is not a numpy array but a list. The reason for this is that if the output is a sequence then CNTK cannot guarrantee that all sequences will be of the same length and it therefore returns a list of arrays, each array being one sequence.

Finally, if you truly have a CNTK variable, you can get the dimensions with `.shape`

Comment: Does "eval()" mean transforming a CNTK variable to numpy array(s)?